# Printing links out in correct format using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, format, html-agility-pack

I’ve been scraping a website using HtmlAgilityPack, but I need the links to print out in the proper format. On the page, I am scraping some of the links include the proper “https://...” formatting at the beginning of the link, however, most start with something else.

For example, a few of the links print starting with “/xxx” or just simply “.//”. Is there any way to sort through the links I have scraped and print the links starting with the proper “https://” format before them?

Currently my code looks like this:

```
var hg = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body[@class]");

//Sort through list and print
foreach (var node in hg)
{
foreach(HtmlNode node2 in node.SelectNodes(".//a[@href]")) 
{
    string attributeValue = node2.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
          if (attributeValue[0:7] != "https://")
   {
    Console.WriteLine("https://url/" + node2.Attributes["href"].Value);
   }
}
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

I’ve been trying to use indexing of the attributeValue string to see what the link starts with, but keep getting an error telling me I can’t use indexing there. Perhaps there is a better way to check the beginning of the links I am unaware of?

I’m a novice at C#, and any help understanding this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try using StartsWith as oppose to trying to index the string

```
var hg = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body[@class]");

//Sort through list and print
foreach (var node in hg)
{
  foreach(HtmlNode node2 in node.SelectNodes(".//a[@href]")) 
  {
      string attributeValue = node2.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
            if (!attributeValue.StartsWith("https://"))
     {
      Console.WriteLine("https://url/" + node2.Attributes["href"].Value);
     }
  }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```